# Not able to access a webelement which is inside a frame in a new window pop up

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, frame

```
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

    public class Iframe {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    WebElement wb;
    try{
    driver.get("http://www.timesjobs.com/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    System.out.println("Old window "+driver.getTitle());
    String old=driver.getWindowHandle();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[1][@class='bdr-left']/a")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    for(String newi:driver.getWindowHandles()){
        driver.switchTo().window(newi);}
    System.out.println("New window "+driver.getTitle());
    wb=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='GB_window']/div[2]/iframe"));
    driver.switchTo().frame(wb);
    wb=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='j_username']"));
    wb.click();
    wb.sendKeys("shantanunandan@gmail.com");
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    driver.switchTo().window(old);
    System.out.println("Old window "+driver.getTitle());     
    }//try
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        driver.close();
        //driver.quit();
    }//catch
    finally{
        driver.close();
        //driver.quit();
    }//finally
   }//main
 }//class
```

By the help of above code I am trying to send some data in a `webelement` names as LogIn.
Here I am trying to send some value in the login id field but when I am clicking on signin button a popup opens. When I right click on the popup then I got an option which says that THIS FRAME then I come to know that its a frame. I tried to switch to it by using `driver.switchTo().frame(wb);` where wb is having the path of the frame. When I run the code I got `NOSuchElement exception` for the `loginid fails` which means the `webdriver` is not able to pass the control to the frame.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you identify  this frame using firebug?

Comment: @Imen Yes i can identify the frame using the fierbug but not in the same window. The thing is once i click on sign in button a pop opens and the frame is inside that pop up. I can identify the frame in that pop up using firebug

Comment: Did you try to switch to you frame like that    driver.switchTo().frame((driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[id='appli']")))); or By.xpath(.....). There is "." in your xpath before "//" try to erase it and execute your script again. NoSuchElment means that something wrong in your xpath identification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed out switching to one more `iframe` i.e., `GB_frame` where your `textbox: username` is present inside this parent `iframe` :- `GB_frame1`

Please add the following to your existing `switchTo()` `frame` code as below:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='GB_frame1']")));
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='GB_frame']")));
```

There is no need to `switchTo` windows, as it's only one window. You can also use `id` instead of `xpath` for locating `iframes`

Comment: Thanks a ton sir. I was looking for a solution from last 2 days but did't found anything. Just because of you the code started working. Thank you sir again. I am a beginner in selenium thats why i want to ask that how you figure it out that there is aframe inside a frame. Can you please share it with me.

Comment: Even i cudn't in the beginning coz their is no issue in the way we `switchTo()` `frames`. If it's not able to `findElement`, you need to checkout if it comes under multiple frames by not just inspecting, but go through the html if you missed out something.

Comment: Sir i went through the html but nerver get inside the code written inside the iframe tags. From now i will check that also

Comment: To come out of the frames i need to use driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); code once or twice?

Comment: Once would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Maybe there are two frames a frame inside a frame. Check the html document and if you finds so then change the code as necessary

 WebElement webele=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='GB_frame1']"));
 driver.switchTo().frame(webele);
 webele=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='GB_frame']"));
 driver.switchTo().frame(weble);
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below code, it will work fine..

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("GB_frame1")));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("GB_frame")));
driver.findElement(By.id("j_username")).sendKeys("TEST");
```